# Intercept Send Command in Outlook OWA (Office 365)

Tags: javascript, jquery, outlook, ms-office

I'm developing an application for Outlook OWA (Office 365). The application is actually very useful for our organization, but have a problem. The application send information using the .post() method of jQuery when a submit button is pressed. How can I attach this task to the "Send" button of Outlook when is being pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would need to handle the Application.ItemSend event. I don't however see how you can use that from your Java code.

How exactly do you display or send the message through Outlook? Does that happen on the client side? Do you just use a mailto link?

Comment: I'm using [office.js](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185(v=office.1501401).aspx) I don't see the Application.ItemSend event. The message will continue the normal flow but the "side" application ask the user for additional information. When the user completes the information that the application request, must press a submit button in the application. I want to make better the application by simplifying this step so the user just click "Send" and the application information is being submitted simultaneously with the message.

Comment: I thought you are using the regular version of Outlook, not OWA, sorry.